# Appositives: Should there be a comma with "that" in this sentence?

Tags: commas, appositives

While writing a sentence like the one below, should I insert a comma after "that movie"(to mean one and only film) or withhold the comma as it is?

Her life was a lot like that movie *Sleepless in Seattle*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to refer to that one specific movie, you would omit a comma, just as you have done. The title of the movie is essential information for determining the identity of the movie her life is being compared to.

[Reference](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/596/01/)